# Sum values from subcategories

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 tables (simplified example in the image below). Table 1 shows the relationship between the Main Codes and Sub Codes; each Main Code can have zero or more Sub Codes. Table 2 shows Sub Codes and a value; Sub Codes can have zero or multiple values. Table 3 shows each unique Main Code and the summary of all values for all Sub Code associated with the Main Code.

The example is much simplified. In reality the code names are meaningless examples and codes don't conveniently start with the same  letter. The third table cannot be created with the pivot table or any other excel construct (like Sub Totals) as in reality it is much more complex and have other structure/formula etc going on in it.

My question is whether it is possible to write a formula for cells H1 and H2 to do indirect sums. In H1 for example ... something like =SUMIF(D:D,"all Sub Code belonging to G1",E:E).

I could write some VBA to do this relatively easily, but I'm trying to work out whether I can achieve the same result with a formula, but can't see how to.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In H1 and copied down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(D$1:D$3)=G1),E$1:E$3)
```

Comment: While I tried to setup the question so that a relationship between the Main Code and Sub Code names didn't exist ... you've prompted to rethink and I can actually set them up that way and then use the answer you've given ... so I'll mark it down as a valid answer in this case. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 3):

If your data was a bit more irregular with no correlation between parent group and child subgroup, you can get correct results by transposing one set of vertical value pairs.

In H1 as an array formula.

```
=SUM(IF(D$1:D$3=TRANSPOSE(B$1:B$4), IF(G1=TRANSPOSE(A$1:A$4), E$1:E$3)))
```